# how to add column and fill it values by conditions between two data frames in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, logic, where-clause

I have the following 2 data set:

**Individual data**

```
   household_id     member_id   channel  event_begin    event_end
0   1                  1          100      83098          83300
1   1                  2          100      83150          83600
2   1                  1          200      83700          83865
3   1                  2          200      83931          83963
4   1                  3          200      84367          84532
5   1                  4          450      84598          84721
6   2                  1          300      83841          83906
7   2                  2          300      78219          78500
```

**Household data**

```
    household_id    channel    Begin     End
  0     1             100      83098    83600
  1     1             200      84367    84532
  2     2             300      83841    83906
  3     2             300      78219    78452
```

I want to add column in `Individual data` as `['FS_NFS']` if `Household data` has same household_id and channel as in Individual data (i.e. Individual and Household data has same id=(household_id&channel))

Now I want put `'FS'` in column `'FS_NFS'` in `Individual Data` if the following condition satisfies

```
(indv['event_begin']>=HH['Begin']) & (indv['event_end']<=HH['End']) & 
       (indv['household_id']==HH['household_id']) & (indv['channel']==HH['channel'])
```

else I I want `'NFS'` in column `'FS_NFS'` in `Individual data`

**Expected O/p:**

```
   household_id     member_id   channel  event_begin    event_end  FS_NFS
0   1                  1          100      83098          83300      FS
1   1                  2          100      83150          83600      FS
2   1                  1          200      83700          83865      NFS 
3   1                  2          200      83931          83963      NFS 
4   1                  3          200      84367          84532      FS
5   1                  4          450      84598          84721      NFS (Channel not prsent in both)
6   2                  1          300      83841          83906      FS
7   2                  2          300      78219          78500      NFS
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve your problem will be to `pd.merge`  individual data with household data by double-key, which will be `household_id` and `channel`

```
data = pd.merge(ind, household, how = 'left', on = ['household_id', 'channel'], left_index = False)
```

Then you can create `FS_NFS` columns based on nonmissing value in `channel_y` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
HH.columns=['household_id','channel','HH_event_Begin','HH_event_End']
merged=pd.merge(indv,HH,on=['household_id','channel'],how='left')

merged['event_begin']=merged['event_begin'].astype(float)#.inplace=True
merged['event_end']=merged['event_end'].astype(float)#.inplace=True
merged['FSNFSNew']=''
i=0
length=len(merged)-1
while i<=length:
    if (merged['event_begin'][i]>=merged['HH_event_Begin'][i])&(merged['event_end'][i]<=merged['HH_event_End'][i]):
        merged['FSNFSNew'][i]='FS'
    else:
        merged['FSNFSNew'][i]='NFS'
    i=i+1
```